# Rendering of polymer element created using template repeat

Tags: polymer

In the below code we are able to create 7 div tags dynamicaly, if we want to change the style of third div how to do it?

```
<template repeat="{{ item in items }}">     
<div id="in">q{{item}}<t>{{user.question[item].time}}<t>{{user.question[item].score}} </div>
<br><br>
</template>
```

the project link in git hub :[quiz element](https://github.com/RohanSingh24/Quiz-element.git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a quick hack

```
<template repeat="{{ item, i in  items }}">     
    <div class="{{i}} question">q{{item}}<t>{{user.question[item].time}}<t>     {{user.question[item].score}} </div>
    <br><br>
</template>
```

And you can use the class name to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a contitional expression with the tokenList filter built in with polymer:

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.3.3/platform.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.3.3/polymer.js"></script>

<polymer-element name="question-list">

  <template>

    <style>
      .thirdQuestion {
        border: 1px solid red;
      }
    </style>

    <template repeat="{{ item, index in  items }}">
      <div class="{{ {thirdQuestion: index === 2} | tokenList }} question">
        {{item}}
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
    </template>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      items: [
        "item 1",
        "item 2",
        "item 3",
        "item 4",
        "item 5",
        "item 6",
        "item 7"
      ]
    });
  </script>

</polymer-element>

<question-list></question-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with [pseudo-selectors](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/) in CSS.

`.question:nth-of-type(3){...}`

[Here is a live example.](http://codepen.io/positlabs/pen/MYoKwN)